# Is there an EF6 DbContext Generator for C# which uses Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, t4, dbcontext, entity-framework-6, fluent-entity-framework

I know that the EF6 VS Tools for Visual Studio 2012 come with a T4 template to generate DbContext classes which work with EF6.

But I want to have a generator which uses fluent API. The older version I used with [EF4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c3351a9-bc39-4de1-ae91-c5ef427836d5) and [EF5](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c) don't work with EF6 and the author no longer works on them to make them EF6 compatible.

Is anyone else working on a generator which uses Fluent API which works with EF6?

Answer (score -2):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

If you have a database you can use reverse code first it will generate all your fluent api mapping.

Comment: this doesn't work. The ReverseEngineerCodeFirst files (Context.tt, Context.tt and mapping.tt) are still EF4/5. I can see this at the using statements.

Comment: You can still use the mappings just reverse code first in a separate project then drag your mappings over. Or wait for the EF team to update the tool.