# Can a mapping class be created in Entity Framework similar to this one in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I want to create a mapping class similar to the one mentioned below. I want to convert this Fluent NHibernate mapping class to Entity Framework.

**Fluent NHibernate**

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

using MyBlog.Core.Objects;


public class PostMap: ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Title)
            .Length(500)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.ShortDescription)
            .Length(5000)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Description)
            .Length(5000)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Meta)
            .Length(1000)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.UrlSlug)
            .Length(200)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Published)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.PostedOn)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Modified);

        References(x => x.Category)
            .Column("Category")
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags)
            .Table("PostTagMap");
    }
}
```

Is NHibernate support available with Hosting Services? Is it easily available with any ASP.NET Hosting or only selected services use it?

Comment: please fix the code formatting to include the **using** into the code. I can't edit the text (I need to add 6 words). stupid limitation.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Formatted. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Entity Framework has the similar mappings.

NHibernate:

```
public PostMap()
{
    Map(x => x.Title)
        .Length(500)
        .Not.Nullable();
}
```

Entity Framework:

```
public class YourDomainModelContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDomainModelContext() { }
    ...
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(u => u.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(500);
    }
}
```

You can get more information in these blog-posts:

- [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)
- [Entity Framework Mapping Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Fluent API vs Data Annotations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476966/FluentplusAPIplusvsplusDataplusAnnotations-plusWor)

Comment: Thanks. I also want to know when is the need to create such a mapping. Is this mandatory?

Comment: No, this mapping is not mandatory. If it is needed to customise your DB, you can use  either Fluent API within `OnModelCreating()` or Data Annotations on Domain Entities' properties. I prefer Fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

For [EF4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c3351a9-bc39-4de1-ae91-c5ef427836d5) and [EF5](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c) there are Fluent API generators, [but for EF6 not. I'm also searching for one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043295/is-there-an-ef6-dbcontext-generator-for-c-sharp-which-uses-fluent-api) that works.